# Can you add variables into a dictionary

Tags: python

I would like to add a [shelf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) to a program and can't seem to add two variables to the dictionary. For example, a username and password that the user inputs. Is this possible? And if so, how could I link them to each other?

```
details=shelve.open['user_details']
details['Name']=username
details['Password']=password
```

So when the user wants to log in I can check if their details are matching, along the lines of:

```
if username and password in details:
    user is logged in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username and password in details:` is not really a proper boolean statement, at least it won't do what you think that does. You are asking *if the variable `username` contains a true value **and** the value of the variable `password` is a member of `details`*. Since `details` is a dictionary, you are asking if the value is a key in the dictionary.

I suspect you want to test if the current username and password stored in the shelve dictionary are equal to the values entered by the user. In that case test against the values:

```
if details['Name'] == username and details['Password'] == password:
    # Username and password are correct, user is logged in.
```

Comment: didnt know that, first one in has to get it so..but thanks to both of you :)